# If $3 \sin B + 5 \cos B =5$, prove that:

Tags: trigonometry

If $3 \sin B + 5 \cos B =5$ then prove that $3\cos B-5\sin B=\pm 3$.

My Attempt

Given:
$$3\sin B+5\cos B=5$$
Dividing both sides by $\cos B$:
$$3\tan B+5=5\sec B$$
Squaring on both sides:
$$9\tan^2 B+30\tan B+ 25=25 \sec^2 B$$

Now, what should I do next?

Comment: Use formula $1+\tan^2B=\sec^2B$ on the RHS. Like this you have a second degree equation in $\tan B$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

$$\begin{align}\color{blue}{(3\sin B+5\cos B)^2}&+\color{green}{(3\cos B-5\sin B)^2}\\
=3^2\sin^2B+2\cdot5\cdot3\sin B\cos B+5^2\cos^2B&+3^2\cos^2B-2\cdot3\cdot5\cos B\sin B+5^2\sin^2B\\
=\color{blue}{5^2}&+\color{green}{3^2}.\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you explain a bit, I could not understand?

Comment: @Iaamuseruser: what don't you understand, this is elementary development ?

Comment: @ Yves Daoust, How does it complete the proof?

Comment: @Iaamuseruser: do you agree that the third line equals the first line ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust hey you can't solve the question this way!! i think so.

Comment: @DeNiSkA: there is nothing wrong with this proof (titled as a hint by the way, but a valid proof indeed). Can you elaborate ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry you are correct!!!!!!

Comment: @DeNiSkA: it is not presented in the usual order, but it is so much nicer this way :)

Comment: yes i will give +1 for this

Answer (score 2):

It's not restrictive to assume $0\le B<2\pi$, since only $\sin B$ and $\cos B$ appear. Note that $B\ne\pi$, because $3\sin\pi+5\cos\pi=-5\ne5$.

Let $t=\tan(B/2)$; then
$$
\frac{6t}{1+t^2}+\frac{5-5t^2}{1+t^2}=5
$$
so
$$
10t^2-6t=0
$$
Therefore either $t=0$ or $t=3/5$.

Now
$$
3\cos B-5\sin B=\frac{3-3t^2}{1+t^2}-\frac{10t}{1+t^2}
$$
and you can substitute the values above.

Comment: $B\neq \pi+2\pi k$, $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @egreg, but how its $B\ne\pi$?

Comment: @Iaamuseruser $3\sin\pi+5\cos\pi=-5\ne5$.

Comment: @user236182 It's not restrictive to assume $0\le B<2\pi$, because only $\sin B$ and $\cos B$ appear.

Comment: @egreg That assumption isn't really universal and should be mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

i can write the first equation as $$6\sin \frac{B}{2}\cos \frac{B}{2}=5(1-cos B)$$
i have used $\sin 2x=2sin\frac{x}{2}cos\frac{x}{2}$ formula
$$1-\cos B=2\sin^2 \frac{B}{2}$$
$$\implies 6\cos \frac{B}2= 5*2\sin \frac{B}{2}$$
here, i have assumed $\sin x$ not equal to $0$, because if $sin x =0$ the answer is straight forward

$$\implies \tan \frac{B}{2}=3/5$$

then you know $\tan x=\frac{opp}{hyp}$
and by pythagoras theorem you can find $sinx$ and $cosx$

and $$\sin B=15/17 , \cos B=8/17$$
on substituting value in the second equation it is proved!!

i hope this method helped

**note:**

conversion of ratios is very helpful

Comment: without $sinx=0$, how should I complete the proof?

Comment: @Iaamuseruser hey i didn't get you sorry?

Comment: if you mean if $sin x=0$ then how will this be proved then the answer is... see the first equation if $sin x =0$ then $cos x$ must be 1, so substitute the value in the second equation and then identity is proved!!

Answer (score 0):

Write $X = 3 \sin B + 5 \cos B = \sqrt{34} \sin (B + \alpha)$ (with $\tan \ \alpha = \frac{5}{3}$ but not needed) then $Y = 3\cos B - 5\sin B = \sqrt{34} \cos( B + \alpha)$, then use $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$.

The details of the calculation are:  You can write $3 \sin B + 5 \cos B$ as $\sqrt{34} (\frac{3}{\sqrt{34}} \sin B + \frac{5}{\sqrt{34}} \cos B)$.

This is OK and it hasn't changed the result, but why divide and multiply by $\sqrt{34}$? That is a bit of experience, but notice that $3^2 + 5^2 = 9 + 25 = 34$.

But now you can put $\cos \alpha = \frac{3}{\sqrt{34}}$ and $\sin \alpha = \frac{5}{\sqrt{34}}$ (you have $\sin^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \alpha = 1$ so that this is admissible) and the final result for $X$ is $\sqrt{34} \sin ( B + \alpha)$.

After that, you can then look at $Y$ and divide and multiply by 6 again and this time you have $Y = 3 \cos B - 5 \sin B = \sqrt{34} (\frac{3}{\sqrt{34}} \cos B - \frac{5}{\sqrt{34}} \sin B) = \sqrt{34} (\cos \alpha \cos B - \sin \alpha \sin B) = \sqrt{34} \cos( B + \alpha)$.

Because $X^2 + Y^2 = 34$ (from $\sin^2 + \cos^2 = 1)$ then $Y^2 = 9, Y = \pm 3$ since you are given $X = 5$.

Comment: could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @http://math.stackexchange.com/users/310149/iaamuser-user have put details in.

Comment: $3^2+5^2\ne 36$. Its $34$. Check the calculation once.

Comment: @Iaamuseruser thanks, what a silly mistake! Corrected.